# Why can't my local environment find generated Proto classes?

Tags: maven, jar, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a project that is set up to compile protobufs specified in my resources directory. To that end, I am using the `xolstice` plugin, with the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protobuf.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is roughly the configuration described [here](https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/examples/protoc-artifact.html). The protos in question include a few object models as well as a GRPC service which I register for use.

The `.jar` is packaged easily enough, with a `maven-jar-plugin` I've inherited from our common root pom. The configuration for that is:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run my project in IntelliJ, everything seems to work fine - I can observe that the required protos are generated correctly and I don't have any issues. However, when I run the `.jar` with `java -jar target/service.jar`, I run into the following issue:

```
[Byte Buddy] ERROR com.artistchooser2.handlers.ChooseArtistsHandler [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5c29bfd, unnamed module @776b83cc, Thread[main,5,main], loaded=false]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot resolve type description for com.artistChooser2.v1.ChooseArtistsServiceGrpc$ChooseArtistsServiceImplBase
    at net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Resolution$Illegal.resolve(TypePool.java:161)
    at net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default$WithLazyResolution$LazyTypeDescription.delegate(TypePool.java:1038)
```

The class which should have been generated by the protocol compilation step seems nowhere to be found. Interestingly, however, I can easily confirm that this seems to be broken by running: `jar -tvf target/service.jar |grep 'ChooseArtistsServiceGrpc$ChooseArtistsServiceImplBase'`. If I run that, I can observe that the class IS actually available and correctly packaged with the `.jar`. I can also verify that in IntelliJ easily enough by perusing through everything within the `.jar`.

I noticed this issue because I was setting up a test that runs my service in a Docker image and verifies that it starts up correctly, as it would in production. Interestingly, however, although I am locally unable to get `mvn verify` to run successfully, my build server (which I have confirmed is running `mvn verify`) runs to completion without issue.

I've checked all of the usual suspects - it has nothing to do with the `maven` build profile that is used on the build server, `maven` versions are the same on the build server and locally, I've even tried clearing the `.m2/repository` in case there was something fishy there.

So I guess my question is whether anyone has any further leads? Is there something else I should be looking into, some sort of environment variable, or anything else that might cause the above exception locally but not on a build server?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm still not entirely sure how exactly this issue manifested - in my `.proto` spec, I had:

```
option java_package = "com.artistChooser2.v1";
```

Interestingly, on my local machine, when I found the compiled protos in the packaged `.jar`, they were appearing under `com.artistchooser2.v1`. Note the lowercase 'c'. But the test I was running was still looking in the upper 'C' package.

For some reason, on the build server, they were actually compiling in the correct location, but not on my local jar. I'm running a Mac, while the build server is a Linux box. Curious if it has something to do with the environment.

Either way, the solution was to alter the package name to what my machine was expecting, which was the lower 'c', probably a better package name anyway.